# How to change table rows to columns according to screen size?

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I would like to render a table differently according to screen size:

- When the screen is small (< `col-md-*`), it should display the data normally on **2 columns**.

[image: Render on small screens]

---

- When the screen is large (`col-md-*` and higher), it should display the data in **4 columns**.

[image: Render on large screens]

---

Here is a [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/Lquon441/) of the following code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="i in items">
        <td>{{i.firstname}}</td>
        <td>{{i.lastname}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Angular object to render**

```
$scope.items = [{
    "firstname": "John", "lastname": "Rambo"
  }, {
    "firstname": "Conor", "lastname": "McCloud"
  }, {
    "firstname": "Bruce", "lastname": "Wayne"
  }, {
    "firstname": "Peter", "lastname": "Parker"
  }, {
    "firstname": "Forrest", "lastname": "Gump"
  }, {
    "firstname": "Patience", "lastname": "Philipps"
  }, {
    "firstname": "Steve", "lastname": "Jobs"
  }, {
    "firstname": "Harry", "lastname": "Potter"
  }
];
```

---

**Notes**

1. I would like to **avoid duplicating code** to do this.
2. I've tried several things, and the easiest way I found is to cut the data in 2 parts, and make a table for each. I don't like to do that, it is too complex, but here is a [**Fiddle for this solution**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/m58zgus6/).
3. I don't need `th` (**Firstname**, **Lastname**), remove them if it's easier.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

I hope this will helps you.

```css
.table{
  margin-bottom: 0px!important;
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .table tr th, .table tr td{
    width: 50%;
  }
  .on-small thead{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
   <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead> 
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Rambo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Conor</td>
            <td>McCloud</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Bruce</td>
            <td>Wayne</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Forrest</td>
            <td>Gump</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>  
      </table>
  </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <table class="table table-striped on-small">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead> 
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Patience</td>
            <td>Philipps</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Steve</td>
            <td>Jobs</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Peter</td>
            <td>Parker</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Harry</td>
            <td>Potter</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>  
      </table>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see the difference with [the solution I evoked](https://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/m58zgus6/) which is to split the data in 2 parts and display it with 2 tables...

Comment: @Mistalis expand this snippet and then check there will be 2 parts dispay and when small screen then it will call media query for **hide** table **head**.

Comment: I saw, but we still have to split data and make 2 tables... :/. As I mentioned in my question, if possible, I would like to avoid this.